# Similating a link click without moving other links

Tags: html, css, sass

Whenever you click a link, I should get a "button press simulation" with `a:active`. What I fail to achieve is that when a link is clicked, it moves all other links and this is because on click, the font size is reduced. How to prevent all other link from moving when the font is increased or decreased on click?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="links">
  <a>Google</a>
  <a>Yahoo</a>
  <a>Facebook</a>
  <a>IBM</a>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.links a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    color: red
  }
}

.links a:active {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: green
}
```

[Click for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sylarruby/jz0tvk59/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you change the size of the font, the 'box' of the link shrinks as well, causing the other elements to the right adjust their position accordingly.

You'll have to at least define a set width to the `<a>` tag using:

```
.link a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: ##px;
}
```

You could also use a unordered list, put the links in the list element, and then style a fixed/min width for the `<li>`

Comment: I've never seen it this way. I'll have a go and confirm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to achieve this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.links a').forEach(function iterateOverLinks(link) {
  // Count chars & multiply it with 12px (depends on the font family & font size)
  link.setAttribute("style", "min-width:" + (link.text.length * 12) + 'px'); 
});
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.links a {
  color: black;
  display: block;     /* Note    */
  float: left;        /* this    */
  text-align: center; /* changes */
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &:hover {
    color: red
  }
}

.links a:active {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Google</a> <!-- a-tags without href are invalid :P -->
  <a href="#">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="#">Facebook</a>
  <a href="#">IBM</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Preferred not to use js for this small bit but thanks.

Comment: Sylar yeah I know, but without a width attribute or a flexbox solution with full width of the `.links` there is no way I think.